# Rate of Evaporation of solution

Tags: aqueous-solution

Why does rate of evaporation of solution decreases on adding a non volatile component?

Also what happens if we add a volatile solute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate of evaporation decreases because the [activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_%28chemistry%29) of the solvent in the liquid phase decreases, while the activity in the vapor phase (or solid, for that matter) stays the same. This is also the reason for the [increase in boiling point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling-point_elevation) and the [decrease in melting point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression) of the solvent.

If we add a volatile solute, it will evaporate too, thus changing the solvent activity in the vapor phase as well. The resulting behavior can't be characterized universally; you'll have to consult the binary phase diagram of boiling for the particular system, and these can be [pretty diverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azeotrope#Positive_and_negative_azeotropes).